# specific fabric binary is not available to download (on raspberry pi)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to set up a hyperledger fabric on raspberry pi 4. I tried many ways but I always get unable to download latest or any hyperledger fabric binaries or " platform specific fabric binary is not available to download". for example the result is like this:

Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9101, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 9101 (delta 13), reused 19 (delta 11), pack-reused 9072
Receiving objects: 100% (9101/9101), 5.14 MiB | 676.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4855/4855), done.
fabric-samples v2.4.0 does not exist, defaulting to main. fabric-samples main branch is intended to work with recent versions of fabric.

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.4.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.4.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-aarch64-2.4.0.tar.gz
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     22      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    22

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.4.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----

I tried so many ways but I always ended up with a **fabric-sample** folder that has no *bin* or fabric binary. Does anyone did have the same trouble and fixed it? Please help. Thank You

Comment: This isn't a *Git* issue. There is simply no https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.4.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-aarch64-2.4.0.tar.gz at all. It doesn't exist (try the URL in a browser). Go to https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/ and observe which releases *are* available (scroll down to "assets").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer/solution on https://githubmate.com/repo/maciejjedrzejczyk/hlf-arm64. I guess for me, the reason why there is a "2.4.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download" is that it's different when installing an hyperledger fabric on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The platforms for Hyperledger Fabric and available images are listed in the [releases page](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases)

We don't build for any ARM based device. Though we do know members of the community have done this; I don't know what the 'state-of-the-art' is.